# Textfield text goes down ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitextfield

I have create on subclass of UITextField to customaize textfield.

My textfield text is proper when I started typung text. On shaking phone I am presenting one viewcontroller. When I present that controller via shaking and then after dismissing text goes down insdie the textfield. See attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Provide complete and relevant code to show how you are adding textfield and presenting/dismissing view controller

Answer (score 0):

Try logging textfield frame before and after shaking of your phone, may be autoresizing of text field changes its frame.

Comment: what about its parent view? I meant the view holding the textfield?